# Add Row into SQL Server Log

Tags: sql-server

How can I programmatically insert a row into either the SQL Error or SQL Server logs on a SQL Server?

I wrote a Dot Net application to do a data import job and would like to write log entries into the SQL Server's log on a failure.

In SSMS, the log can be found Management-SQL Server Log.

I can pull the contents of the error and SQL Server log by the stored procedure **xp_readerrorlog**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to the SQL Server error logs via the t-sql `RAISERROR` command.

See this [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497(v=sql.105).aspx) article.

Answer (score 1):

One of the following will do it from T-SQL.

[xp_logevent](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186244(v=sql.110).aspx)

[RAISERROR … WITH LOG](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592(v=sql.110).aspx)

Structured Exception Handling (including the [THROW](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615(v=sql.110).aspx) statement) is the intended replacement for RAISERROR, starting in SQL Server 2012, but THROW does not have WITH LOG functionality.